# Foreign Key Constraint in Stored Procedure - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following stored procedure, I have two tables here, Movie and Director.  Both need to be updated when a new movie has been created or added.  How do you handle FKs in stored procedures?  The FK in this case is `director_id`.  It is a primary key in `Director` but a FK in `Movie`  Do I need to specify it twice like so?  I am getting conflict errors

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Book_Book_Creation
    @Book_id_arg DECIMAL(12),    
    @author_id_arg DECIMAL(12),    
    @type_id_arg DECIMAL(12),     
    @title_arg VARCHAR(64),      -
    @copyright_arg DECIMAL(4),   
    @dauthor_id_2_arg DECIMAL(12),    
    @author_fname_arg VARCHAR (64), 
    @author_lname_arg VARCHAR (64)  
AS
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO Book(Book_id, author_id,genre_id, title, copyright)
    VALUES (@author_arg, @author_id_arg,  @type_id_arg, @title_arg, @copyright_arg);
    INSERT INTO Author(author_id, author_fname, author_lname)
    VALUES (@director_id_2_arg, @director_fname_arg, @director_lname_arg)
END;

EXECUTE Book_Book_Creation 32,32,1,'Tempting',2013,32,'Taylor','Mendez';
```

Comment: In that case, you need to insert the director first, then fetch it's newly generated by `SELECT @NewDirectorID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and then insert the values into the movie table with the new director's ID

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you just need to do this:

- insert into the `Director` table first
- get the newly inserted ID from that table (assuming that the `Director_Id` column is your primary key and is of type `INT IDENTITY`)
- then insert into the `Movie` table with that new ID

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @NewDirectorID INT

INSERT INTO Director (Director_id, Director_fname, director_lname)
VALUES (@director_id_2_arg, @director_fname_arg, @director_lname_arg)

SELECT @NewDirectorID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO Movie (Movie_id, director_id,genre_id, title, copyright)
VALUES (@movie_id_arg, @NewDirectorID,  @genre_id_arg, @title_arg, @copyright_arg);
```

I don't see why you would pass in the director's ID as a parameter - twice!

Comment: I am very new to DB, how would I implement that into my procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Movie_Movie_Creation12

    @movie_id_arg DECIMAL(12),  
    @director_id_arg DECIMAL(12),
    @genre_id_arg DECIMAL(12), 
    @title_arg VARCHAR(64),
    @copyright_arg DECIMAL(4),  
    @director_fname_arg VARCHAR (64), 
    @director_lname_arg VARCHAR (64) 

AS BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO dbo.Director (Director_id, Director_fname, director_lname)
    SELECT @director_id_arg, @director_fname_arg, @director_lname_arg

    INSERT INTO dbo.Movie (Movie_id, director_id,genre_id, title, copyright)
    SELECT @movie_id_arg, @director_id_arg,  @genre_id_arg, @title_arg, @copyright_arg

END

EXECUTE dbo.Movie_Movie_Creation12  
            @movie_id_arg = 32 
        ,   @director_id_arg = 32
        ,   @genre_id_arg = 1
        ,   @title_arg = 'Argo'
        ,   @copyright_arg = 2012
        ,   @director_fname_arg = 'Ben'
        ,   @director_lname_arg = 'Affleck'
```